# How to resolve the issue of (ValidationException) in AWS DynamoDB while working with CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, put, dynamo-local

I was just learning AWS DynamoDB in CLI. i was specifically performing `put-item` using command 
`aws dynamodb put-item --table-name new --item file://item.json`. I have successfully configured the IAM credentials and I'm also able to get the responce back using
 `aws dynamodb list-tables` :

`{
    "TableNames": [
        "new",
        "test"
    ]
}`

ERROR:

[image: Validation Error]

I'm specifically this error: `An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key newid in the item`

can anyone please guide me how to get out of this and fix this error?

Comment: What is your partition key?

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 test_id (String)

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 Yureka. i got it thanks for giving hint

Comment: In case you need it, there are examples of this in the getting started section of the DynamoDB documentation for CLI and most SDKs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i was the one who asked this question and thanks to [@krishna_mee2004](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4191049/krishna-mee2004) for giving hint to my problem.
the main issue was that i had specified partition key as `test_id` and i was using it as `user_id`.

my previous format in `item.json` was

```
    {
    "user_id":{"S":"123add"},
    "ForumName": {"S": "Amazon DynamoDB"},
    "Subject": {"S": "New discussion thread"},
    "Message": {"S": "First post in this thread"},
    "LastPostedBy": {"S": "fred@example.com"},
    "LastPostDateTime": {"S": "201603190422"}
}
```

but i just replaced `user_id` with `test_id`:

```
   {
    "test_id":{"S":"123add"},
    "ForumName": {"S": "Amazon DynamoDB"},
    "Subject": {"S": "New discussion thread"},
    "Message": {"S": "First post in this thread"},
    "LastPostedBy": {"S": "fred@example.com"},
    "LastPostDateTime": {"S": "201603190422"}
}
```

which was the actual partition key of my AWS DynamoDB table and voila it worked:

i Successfully created a table list:

[image]